# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sqrt[n]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}}$ given the sum converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$a_{n}>0$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converge. Find the value of $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sqrt[n]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AM-GM inequality shows that $(n-k)(a_{k+1}a_{k+2}\cdots a_n)^{1/(n-k)}\leqslant\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^na_i\leqslant\sum\limits_{i\geqslant k+1}a_i$ for every $k$ and every $n\geqslant k$, hence $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}(n-k)(a_{k+1}a_{k+2}\cdots a_n)^{1/(n-k)}\leqslant\sum\limits_{i\geqslant k+1}a_i$. Now, use three facts:

- for every $k$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n/(n-k)=1$,
- for every $k$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_1a_2\cdots a_{k})^{1/n}=1$,
- by choosing $k$ large enough, $\sum\limits_{i\geqslant k+1}a_i$ can be made as close to zero as desired,

to conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{1/n}=0$.