# Calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n^x (a_1 a_2\dots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, exponential-function

> Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is  a sequence such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} {n^x}a_n=a $ for some real $\,x$. Calculate
> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n^x (a_1\,a_2\dots\,a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

**My attempts :** I take  $a_1=a_2 = \dots =a_n = a$

after that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $n^x (a_1\,a_2 \dots \,a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=  \infty \, a = \infty$

Is it correct ?? or not

Please help me.

Any hints/soluion.....

Comment: Or this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/352935/42969.

Comment: Well, the first error that you make is in taking $a_i = a$. Since, then $\lim n^x a_n = a \lim n^x $ which equals $0$ if $x<0$, $a$ if $x=0$ and $\text{sign}(a)\infty$ if $x>0$.

Comment: @MartinR  Setting $x_n:=n^xa_n$ in your first link doesn't seem to work here.  At least, one needs to do more.  Hence, this problem is not a duplicate of the first link (nor the second link).

Comment: @Batominovski: With that substitution, $x_n \to a$ and therefore $n^x (a_1.a_2......a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (x_1x_2\dots x_n)^{1/n} \to a$. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: No, there will be an extra factor.  Note $$n^x\,\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\,a_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{n^x}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\,i^x\right)^{\frac1n}}\,\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\,x_i\right)^{\frac1n}=\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{\frac{x}{n}}\,\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\,x_i\right)^{\frac1n}\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski: You are right, my fault.

Comment: @MartinR But please don't delete both links.  They are very useful to this problem.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This is not a duplicate.  Please read the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $a_n> 0$ for every positive integer $n$;  otherwise the limit may not exist.  Set $z_n:=n^x\,a_n$ like Martin R recommended.  Thus,
$$n^x\,\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\,a_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{n^x}{\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\,i^x\right)^{\frac1n}}\,\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\,z_i\right)^{\frac1n}=\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{\frac{x}{n}}\,\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\,z_i\right)^{\frac1n}\,.$$
Now, since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\,z_n=a$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\,z_i\right)^{\frac1n}=a$ (see Martin R's [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711597/if-lim-n-to-inftyx-n-alpha-show-lim-n-to-inftyx-1x-2-dots-x-n1-n) in the comments above).  Furthermore, Stirling's approximation $n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{\text{e}}\right)^n$ implies that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{\frac{x}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\left(\frac{\text{e}^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)^{\frac{x}{n}}=\exp(x)\,.$$ Consequently, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\,n^x\,\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\,a_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=a\,\exp(x)\,.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since
$a_n \approx an^{-x}$,

$\begin{array}\\
n^x (\prod_{k=1}^na_k)^{\frac{1}{n}}
&\approx n^x \left(\prod_{k=1}^n(ak^{-x})\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&= n^x \left(a^nn!^{-x}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&= n^x a\left(n!^{1/n}\right)^{-x}\\
&\approx n^x a\left(n/e\right)^{-x}\\
&= ae^{x}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $b_n=n^{nx} a_1 a_2\dots a_n$ and then $b_{n+1}/b_n=(1+n^{-1})^{nx}(n+1)^xa_{n+1}\to e^xa$ and hence $b_n^{1/n}\to ae^x$.